# "It isn't tastes good or fresh." Is it correct?

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs, subject-verb-agreement

> "It isn't tastes good or fresh."

Is it correct?
My teacher said it's grammar mistake 
and I don't know what the correct form is.

Comment: You've got two main verbs in one sentence, *is* and *tastes*.  Only one is allowed.  To get your negative sense, say "it *doesn't* taste good."  The second verb form *does* isn't a main verb; it's an auxiliary to help with the sense of the main verb *tastes*.

Answer (score 3):

Taste is both a noun and verb. When a verb is used for the third person to form the present simple, you add s after it. For example, it tastes good/fresh.

To form a negative, you should use doesn't before the infiniive taste as it is used for the third person. So the correct sentence is:

It doesn't taste good/fresh.

Answer (score -1):

The correct form of usage is  "It doesn't taste good or fresh"

Comment: Please add some more information to address this question. This better goes as a comment as it is.